# Loading vector layers from database/ schema using login username and password in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a QGIS setup with a PostgreSQL / PostGIS database on a server and multiple clients.

I have created schemas in the database for each user. With a username password combination, each user is able to connect to his/ her schema to load his/ her vector layers.

I want to create a common QGIS project for all users which users will download onto the client PCs from a shared location. When the project file is opened, the users should enter their username and password to get connected to their respective schema, and the layers should get loaded.

I am able to do this by creating separate project files for each user, but how do I achieve it with a single project file?

Answer (score 0):

Create a project and import your separate  projects earlier made by you using Layer > Embed Layer and Groups. Select the layer which you want to add. Similarly add another project.